# Delete a value in a sorted Linked list

Tags: c++, list, nodes

Hey I created a function that inserts inputed values into a sorted linked list, and now I'm trying to create another function to delete an entered value in a linked list. Currently I am getting an infinite loop of rick james and it is incredibly frustrating.

```
typedef int ListItemType; // global value in my header file
ListItemType item;  // assigned in head file under ListNode struct

bool List::remove(const ListItemType& removedItem) {
ListNode *curr = head;
ListNode *prev = NULL;

//empty list
if(head == NULL){
    cout<< "No items in the list";
}else{

    //traverse the list
while(curr != NULL){
    if(curr->item == removedItem){
        break; //data has been found break loop
    }else{
        //increment loop
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}//end while
    //data has not been found
if(curr == NULL){
        cout << "RICK JAMES";
}else{
    //data has been found delete data
        // case 1: delete at head node
    if(head == curr){
            head = head->next;
    }else{
        // case 2: delete after head
            prev->next = curr->next;
        }   
                delete curr;
                size--; 
            return true;
    }
 } 
   return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

the function logic looks ok to me...

If you're getting "RICK JAMES" all the time, it means it can not find the node to delete - may be something's wrong with the way you compare node's value with the function parameter...

function accepts

> ListItemType& removedItem

which seems a little bit weird for int datatype, but I'm not sure how's the "item" field defined in ListNode... I would suggest to double check this. Good luck!

Comment: So i got rid of ListItem type and just have int item now in the struct of my node, and I removed if(curr == NULL) statement and printed out the value of curr->item at that point in the loop and found that it was properly looping and than deleting the value. Except after it deletes the value it should end, instead it goes on and now I get a unhandled execption NULL reference exception, object reference not set to an instance of an ojbect.

Comment: So in the debugger I found that prev->next = curr->next; is the line that is causing me to crash but I have no clue why

Comment: uggg. So i got it to work all i needed was a return statement after the two cases

Comment: well, you have some "return true" there, but ok, at least it's working ;).